# How to override this inbuilt style which has !important applied

Tags: css

I tried to overide this style by copying the same css

```
[class^="icon-"], [class*=" icon-"] {
        font-family: 'SilkWeb4' !important;
        font-style: norm}
```

Tried with

```
[class^="icon-"], [class*=" icon-"] {
            font-family: arial !important;
            font-style: norm}
```

and instead of SilkWeb4 have applied arial !important; still have no luck with the result.
Is there a way to override this?

Comment: make sure your style is added later

Answer (score 0):

Apply more precise selector. You probably don't have to use !important at all:

https://css-tricks.com/when-using-important-is-the-right-choice/

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity

Comment: Specific class name is icon-text. So I tried
{
            font-family: arial;
            font-style: norm} Yet no luck. Not sure what mistake I have made

Comment: I mean you should add more selectors to this css rule:
div#someid[class^="icon-"] ..... etc.

Answer (score 0):

Use an ID to increase the specifity. A random ID inside `:not()` will do the job:

```
[class^="icon-"]:not(#randomID), [class*=" icon-"]:not(#randomID) {
        font-family: arial !important;
        font-style: normal
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Instead of copying , why dont you just replace the font it's literally one word, no offence your question is absolutely valid , it was just a suggestion. Use this :

```
[class^="icon-"]:not(#randomID), [class*=" icon-"]:not(#randomID) {
    font-family: arial !important;
    font-style: normal
```

}

The code provided by @Temani Afif , that is correct

Comment: why are you repeating my answer?